# Solutions to blocking operations inside an epoll event loop

Tags: c, sockets, concurrency, server, epoll

I have an epoll event loop in my TCP server to handle client connections and read data from clients.

```
while(1) {
    int n, i;

    n = epoll_wait(efd, events, 64, -1); // This is blocking. It waits till new events arrive

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if((events[i].events & EPOLLERR) || (events[i].events & EPOLLHUP) || (!(events[i].events & EPOLLIN))) {
          /* An error has occured on this fd, or the socket is not
             ready for reading */
      dzlog_error("epoll error: %s", strerror(errno));
      close(events[i].data.fd);

      continue;
    } else if(sock == events[i].data.fd) { // Event on the server socket. Accept client connection
            while(1) {
                if((cli = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_size)) == -1) {
                    if((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) { // We have processed all incoming connections
                        break;
                    } else {
                        dzlog_error("accept: %s", strerror(errno));
                        break;
                    }
                }

                dzlog_info("Client connected: Identifier - %d", cli);

                s = fcntl(cli, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); // Make client socket non-blocking
               if(s == -1) {
                    dzlog_error("Client no block: %s", strerror(errno));
                    close(cli);
                    break;
                }

                event.data.fd = cli;
                event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
                s = epoll_ctl (efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, cli, &event); // Add the client socket to the list of file descriptors to poll
                if(s == -1) {
                    dzlog_error("epoll_ctl: %s", strerror(errno));
                    close(cli);
                    break;
                }
            }

            continue;
        } else {
            readClientData(events[i].data.fd);
        }
    }
}
```

When there is data to be read from the client socket, the `readClientData` function is called. Lets assume that inside that function, we have a call to a database that fetches some data from a table. If for some reason, the call to the database hangs or takes longer than expected, other clients waiting to be connected or send data will also be blocked.

For example consider the following scenario:

1. Client 1 connects to server
2. Client 2 connects to server
3. Client 1 sends data to server (this will cause the `readClientData` function to be called to process the data)
4. `readClientData` function calls the database and waits for response. (waits for 10 seconds or might hang indefinitely)
5. Client 2 sends data. This data can't be processed as the server is still waiting for the `readClientData` to complete for Client 1
6. A new Client 3 tries to connect but has to wait for its connection to be accepted because server is still processing data from Client 1

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Why not have the server fork the process on a successful connection?

Comment: @Chirality that would be horrible for performance which is why I've chosen the even-driven approach

Comment: I should have clarified. Can you not fork the `readClientData` function so that the server (parent process) continues to accept and process connections in this event-driven approach? I'm not sure you can get around waiting for it to execute the function otherwise.

Comment: @Chirality Won't that be same as having a child process per connection? If I have 50k clients all sending data, I'll have 50k child processes

Comment: That's definitely a worst-case scenario and assuming the server doesn't process a single request by the time they all finish connecting. There's absolutely no way around doing the `readClientData` function simultaneously. Whether you can thread it or fork it is up to you, but the current implementation, as you said, is a queue approach.

Comment: I suggest learning how node.js works - even if you don't write your application in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can dedicate separate process for waited operations like database read, listening on socket as well, so that you can use your event loop to check send/recv completes for your DB process as well

And Keep event loop in main process:
Read from client,write to DB handling process in nowait mode,come back to event loop to check for DB process reply or new request from client

Answer (score 0):

**Unnecessary Sequentialisation?**

Assuming that your mention of `readClientData()` making a database query is germane; databases are quite clever, any half decent engine these days can quite happily serve more than one client at a time. If there's no particular reason why a client shouldn't talk directly to the database, having them do so would likely make for a faster system.

**More Than One Database Shim Required**

If that's not an option, using a process/thread to be a shim between your main event loop and the database (as desribed by Pras) is one way of keeping the event loop response time low.

However, you may as well have more than one of these, so that a client making a short request isn't held up by another client that's just made a long request. With a single shim, it'd be getting held up waiting for the long request to complete before even starting the new, short request.

This starts getting complex; you need multiple processes/threads, you have to work out a way to divide up the incoming requests amongst the shims, etc. That's a lot of code to start writing.

**ZeroMQ**

Fortunately there is an answer; if you use ZeroMQ for the communications between the main event loop and the database shims, you can start exploiting its patterns (= you're not writing a ton of code yourself). PUSH/PULL comes to mind; that can be used to auto-magically farm out client requests amongst the shims.

If you get the high water marks right, new client requests could "overtake" a long running request, because the long running shim simply wouldn't be given the new client request. Provided of course that the database engine itself can actually serve all the shims simultanously.